# Trying to call javascript code from java

Tags: javascript, java

I have JavaScript code which uses another JavaScript source:

```html
<body>
  <script src="node_modules/node-vibrant/dist/vibrant.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(src) {
      Vibrant.from(src).getPalette(function(err, swatches) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var key in swatches) {
          if (key === "Vibrant") {
            var swatch = swatches[key];
            if (swatch) {
              console.log("hex: " + swatch.getHex());
              return (swatch.getHex());
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }

    test("Apples.jpg");
  </script>
</body>
```

I want to call this code in Java. How to do that?

I was trying to use the `ScriptManager` but got an error which said:

> window in not defined

Comment: Assuming [that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vibrant)'s the module: "node-vibrant@1.x is a node.js port of Vibrant.js, which is a javascript port of the awesome Palette class in the Android support library." So using the original library seems like a good idea (you'll have to "disandroid" maybe)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
 ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

            // JavaScript code in a String
            String script = " function test(src) {   Vibrant.from(src).getPalette(function(err, swatches) {        if (err) throw err;          for (var key in swatches) {    if(key==='Vibrant'){          var swatch = swatches[key];          if (swatch) {        console.log('hex: ' + swatch.getHex());            return(swatch.getHex());              }}        }      });    }";
            // evaluate script
            engine.eval(script);


            Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;

            // invoke the global function named "hello"
            inv.invokeFunction("test", "Apples.jpg" );
```

Comment: Vibrant in the script is used from the script src. Without that it will throw error